# Function local variable persists between function calls

Tags: c++, mbed

I wrote a simple dot product function on an MBED LPC1768:

```
float dotProduct(float a[], float b[], int length){
    float sum;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++){
        sum = sum + a[i]*b[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I have two calls to dotProduct in a row in my program that (for testing) dot two 128 element 1-vectors ({1,1,1...1}) and print them to serial. So the expected result should just be 128 and 128. The variable `sum` seems to persist, however, because I get 128 and 256. Furthermore, if I change the `float sum` declaration to `float sum = 0`, I get the desired result of 128 and 128. The variable `sum` is not static, so why does it persist between function calls? Thanks

Comment: You using an uninitialized variable -> results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with "persistence" is that `sum` is used uninitialized, hence causing undefined behavior. In your case, however, `sum` gets allocated in the same place in memory where it has been during the prior invocation, thus creating an illusion of "persistence".

Note that your compiler has probably issued a warning to you, which you should not have ignored.

Fix this problem by adding initialization to your variables before using them:

```
float sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    sum = sum + a[i]*b[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have UB as you read from an uninitialized variable and it pretty much useless to discuss what particular side effects of undefined behavior you have.